# Chrome extension - MediaStream on content_scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mediastream

How can I pass a MediaStream object(popup.js) to content_scripts?

**popup.js it's my javascript included on my html file from "browser_action" on manifest.json**

manifest.json

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "css": ["content-style.css"],
            "js": ["content.js", "fontawesome.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "desktopCapture", "tabCapture"]
```

I want to make an chrome extension that records the user current tab. I can capture the tab on the popup.js side. I tried to use sendMessage, but I think it can only accept simple objects.

popup.js

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio: true, video: true}, function(tab){

  console.log(tab); // MediaStream that I needed

  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
    let msg = {
      actionMessage: 'popup-open'
    };

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg);
  });
});
```

content_scripts.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.actionMessage === 'popup-open') {
    // do something and start recording  
  }
});
```

today, i'm using the code below on my content_scripts.js, but the only tab that I need to record, it's the tab that call the extension.

```
let tabStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
```

I needed this to be the MediaStream that I got from my popup.js, so I don't need to ask the user to always share the current screen tab.

I saw that every MediaStream has an id(hash), don't know if is it possible to use that to capture the mediastream on my content_scripts.

Is it possible to do this or I need to generate the whole recording on my popup or background scripts?